# POST method dont see append() elements (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, post, append

jQuery code add new virtual object ".add" to object ".main"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.main').on('click', '.add', function (){
    $('.main').append('<div class="add">Next element</div><input type="hidden" name="param[]" value="Next element"/>');
});
});

</script>
```

HTML code with form "main":

```
<form action="" method="post" class="main">
    <div class="add">First element</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="param[]" value="First element"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="go"/>
</form>
```

PHP iterate "param" array:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    foreach ($_POST['param'] as $element) 
    {
        echo '<br/>'.$element;
    }
}
```

In $_POST will not have a element that was appended by jquery. How to fix?

Comment: I'm not seeing the questio here, nor understand what PHP has to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of this:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="param[]" value="Next element"/>
```

I tried this once too, doing the `[]` doesnt work you must put an actual index in there like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="param[1]" value="Next element"/>
```

Best way is to count the length of the items you already have and make the index of the element that.

So you code would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.main').on('click', '.add', function (){
        var i = $('.my_input').length-1; // Because its an array
        $('.main').append('<div class="add">Next element</div><input class="my_input" type="hidden" name="param['+i+']" value="Next element"/>');
    });
});
```

Notice how I have added the class to the input?

#### Edit

Here is one that will definitely work with your current HTML

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.main').on('click', '.add', function (){
        var i = $('input[name*="param"]').length-1; // Because its an array
        $('.main').append('<div class="add">Next element</div><input type="hidden" name="param['+i+']" value="Next element"/>');
    });
});
```

Could be better opitmised still but meh...

Comment: hard way, new elements i get by AJAX and dont know how many exists and how many get

Comment: They are on the page right? Just count what's on the page.... I have added some code

Comment: It only needs to be done for new elements not one you add to the base html.

Comment: you don't have to add an index. adding `[]` to the `name` attribute creates an array inside the post array, so you'd need to iterate through the second array inside your first loop, indidentally, that's why it appears to not show up.  Do a `var_dump` you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch Does it? Wouldn't have seen "Array" output on the echo of his $_POST vars instead of the data he was looking for but not the new items?

Comment: he's only echoing the value's, not the key/value pair, so without handling value's in the next dimension, I don't think it would even access them to render. That's why I wanted him to `var_dump`... if that array is in there, that would expose it and help him handle.

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch Yea but if you look at his code: he is making one $_POST array of param[] and then adding a new param[]. He knows that, he foreachs his param array echoing out the value of the element. He was not denoting nested array elements cos then PHP would echo the class out as a string and so would echo "Array" to him instead of the values he was asking and so his question would have been about that however it was not. He already knew params was an array in $_POST, that's why he foreachs it, his problem was that he wasn't getting the new values.

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch You seem to have been suggesting that param[] is an array and he doesnt know it so you get him to var_dump the value to prove it is an array, but he already foreachs that array and gets his original values out but not his new ones cos they ain't in there so your original comment kinda doesn't make sense.